# A website where I can evaluate a definite integral and also get a step-by-step solution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, online-resources

Does anyone know of a site where I can evaluate a definite integral and also get a step-by-step solution?

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As @DannyCheuk mentioned, if you pay, you could get for a long time, unless you start solving them yourselves.

Answer (score 2):

Wolframalpha, I believe you get like 3 free everyday, and 2.99/month for students, else 4.99/month.

Also, I believe they're running some sort of ... sales right now, that you get 3 months for free with an annual subscription.  Just google it.

Comment: i tried it on wolfram alpha, but there is no option for a stepwise solution.

Comment: @SamSharma If you omit the bounds by asking Wolfram|Alpha to evaluate the **indefinite** integral, there will be an option for a stepwise solution.

Comment: @Adriano The integral to be evaluated was not completed even with extended computaion time, any other advice

Comment: Get Mathematica ... most universities offer them for free or very low cost to students